# background [v2.1] package extraneous output using backgroundsetup

Tags: backgrounds

While using the new `background` package (v2.1, 4 Mar 2014) with minimal LaTeX commands in `\backgroundsetup`, I receive a centered text as `-1000pt` in a classic "Draft" watermark style.

I have tried combinations of, `[pages=all]` option in package declaration, `\backgroundsetup`, yet this output persists.

**Edit:**

Sorry about the previous code, I removed the newlines in the code and it has compiled correctly with the same output.

I am using `textblock` to position particular text at a specific location, say over a logo image.

MWE is as follows.

**Code**

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{textblock}{50}(100,20) {\large {\textcolor{black}{Sometext}}} \end{textblock}%
}}
\begin{document}
HelloWorld!
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Any pointers on rectifying this extraneous output would greatly help.

Comment: Your code produces errors; please fix them. Why are you using `textblock` in the contents of background?

Comment: According to the description in your edit, perhaps `background` is not the right package to do this: first, it makes no sense to use `textpos` in the contents; background uses its own mechanism to place the material in the desired position and to control the attributes; second, if you want to place some material over an image, don't use `background`: as the documentation of the package states, `background` places its contents in the background.